# What color hair does he have?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a question regarding asking about hair color.
Someone wrote this to me recently:
There are only 2 situations when such a question is being asked:

1. The person who was asked has many heads, each head has a different
   color hair --> this situation is quite unusual in our real life.
2. The person who was asked has a wig collection with many different
   colors --> again, this situation is quite unusual. Suggestion to
   change:

What's her hair color? or What color is her hair? 
I honestly thought that "What color hair does he/she have?" is a natural way of asking. Am I wrong?

Comment: "What's her hair color?" and "What color is her hair?" are both slightly more natural than "What color hair does she have?" (IMO), but the latter doesn't sound very weird at all. I'd be interested in seeing frequency data.

Comment: I don't find *anything* wrong with, "What color hair does she have." I'd *never* have come up with anything about multiple heads or wigs, and it's probably what I'd naturally say.  "What's her hair color" is probably a phrasing I'd never come up with myself in conversation- I *would* use "What color is her hair."

Comment: Agreeing with Jim, and also want to say that to me "What color hair does she have" seems like a question you would ask if you were searching for the person - i.e. a police officer asking a witness, looking for a suspect, or you're looking through a photo with multiple people in it.

Comment: Actually, after some reflection, I *might* ask, “What’s her hair color?” if I was at the store in the hair color aisle...